# android gridview height set

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview inside the scrollview. The content (number of rows) of the gridview is subject to change after the SimpleAdapter is applied. However, the height of the gridview  remains the same.

Do you know how to change the height of the gridview dynamically? I have tried out several ways to set the the height of the gridview but none of them works.

Here are part of my code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 500);
p.topMargin = 60;
p.height = 600;
gridView.setLayoutParams(p);
```

But with the methods above, the height of the gridview remains the same...

The onMeasure method of the gridview is overridden:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    if(isExpanded()){
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }else{
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

Part of the XML file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/advanced_interface"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="ntu.fyp.sjy.securitycontroller.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/contact_source" 
        android:layout_width="60dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" 
        android:text="@string/contact"/>

    <Switch 
        android:id="@+id/contact_source_switch" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/contact_source" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/contact_source"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:onClick="contactSourceToggle"/>

    <ntu.fyp.sjy.securitycontroller.MyGridView
        android:id="@+id/contact_source_grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_source"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the xml code to be adapted in the gridview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:shrinkColumns="0">

<TableRow
    android:id = "@+id/source_tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/source_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/source_app_title"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/source_app_check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id = "@+id/source_tableRow_internet"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity = "center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sink_internet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/internet"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/sink_internet_check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id = "@+id/source_tableRow_file"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity = "center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sink_file"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/file"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/sink_file_check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</TableRow>
```

The table row source_tableRow_file & source_tableRow_internet might be set to visible or gone according to the user input. How can I adjust the height of gridview according to the total number of rows??

Comment: in parent scroll view put android:fillViewport="true" property. it will allow scroll view to fill full height or extend if require.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this, but it couldn't help.

Comment: any other suggestion?